# Compute error term of approximation using Taylor series without knowing the function?

Tags: numerical-methods

I am asked to compute error term of approximation using Taylor Series with a relation between function itself and its first-order derivative, for example:
$f'(x) = \frac{1}{2h}[f(x+h)-f(x-h)]$.
I wonder how to do this if I don't know details about $f(x)$? I don't see ways to compute $f(x)$ from this either.

Answer (score 0):

Use
$$
f(x\pm h)=f(x)±f'(x)h+\frac12 f''(x)h^2±\frac16f'''(x)h^3+O(h^4).
$$

---

You could also apply L'Hopital or the mean-value formula to the difference of both sides.
\begin{align}
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)-2hf'(x)}{2h^3}
&=\frac{f'(x+h_1)+f'(x-h_h)-2f'(x)}{6h_1^2}\\
&=\frac{f''(x+h_2)-f''(x-h_2)}{12h_2}\\
&=\frac{f'''(x+h_3)+f'''(x-h_3)}{12}
\end{align}
with $h\ge h_1\ge h_2\ge h_3\ge 0$.